# Exact months between in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I want to find EXACT months between two dates in SAS. I was using INTCK to do this.

```
 DATA dataset;
      set dataset;
       months_exact = intck ('months'. dob, doe);
  RUN;
```

Right now if I had the date Oct 1, 2007  and  Nov 15, 2011 it gives me 49 months I want it to give me 49.47 months. But I want to do this for the whole dataset without having to look to deal with months having different lengths of time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Count the number of days and divide by 30.4375

Comment: but that's not always exact...

Comment: You need to provide an algorithm for what you consider is an EXACT fraction of a month.

Comment: Not sure it doesn't match the instructions on the page I'm preparing the data for in the example data. But that varies by other calculators. It's close so I guess I would have to figure out what algorithms are available. This might be close enough I'll check

Comment: I think @superfluous has the best solution. Using `intck` and/or `intnx` will give imprecise results in some situations. For instance, try using start dates `29JAN2016` thru `31JAN2016` with end date `29FEB2016` with @DomPazz's solution, and you'll get 1.00 in all three cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the fraction of the end month:

Get the 49 number like you are doing now.

Find the number of days between the start and end.

```
days = end - intnx('month',start,months,'sameday');
```

Then find the number of days in the ending month.

```
days_month = intnx('month',end,0,'end') - intnx('month',end,0,'begin') + 1;
```

Then add the fraction.

```
months_exact = months + days/days_month;
```